# Salesforce Campaign to Exact Target campaign

Tags: marketing-cloud, campaign, marketing-cloud-connect

I have created campaigns in Salesforce is there is any way we can link the same to Marketing Cloud campaigns.

So I can see all my salesforce campaigns in Marketing Campaign View.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Campaign & Marketing Campaign doesnt have any integration and cant be interlinked.

What you can do is to come up with a campaign code and track that in Marketing Cloud and Salesforce campaign. this is a manual process and just for informative purposes.